# Java -syntax and logical errors that i cannot find the answer to

Tags: java, arrays

Java program  not running properly and i can't tell what the problem is 
also i have the constructor and I'm about to add it
their quite a few of problems but I'm not sure how to fix them so if anyone would be willing to help id greatly appreciate it

//Header files

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Phonedir
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    String First_name, Last_name, Phone_Num;
    String First, Last, Num;
    int choice=0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    LinkedList<T> listOfTs = new LinkedList<T>();

    System.out.println("A Program to keep a Phone Directory:");

    //looping menu
    while(true)
    {
        Menu();

      //enter the choice
      if(choice==0)
        System.out.println("No choice selected");
      else  
        System.out.println(listOfTs.get(choice-1));

      System.out.print("Enter the choice ");
        String command = in.next().trim();

      //show all entries
      if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
      {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(First_name+" "+Last_name+" "+Phone_Num);


        //for loop
        for(int i=0; i<listOfTs.size(); i++)
          System.out.println(listOfRecords.get(i));

      }

      //Delete choice
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Deleted: "+listOfRecords.remove(choice-1));
          choice=0;          //update choice counter of reference of linked list
        }

      }

      //change first name of choice Record
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("New first name: ");
            First = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).changeFirst(First);
        }
      }

      //Change last name of selected record
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("New last name: ");
            Last = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).changeLast(Last);
        }
      }

      //add new contact

      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
      {
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
                First_name = in.next().trim();
        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
                Last_name = in.next().trim();
        //check in valid phone number input
        //if phone number does not equal 10 then reprompt
        while(true)
        {
          System.out.print("Enter phone number");
                  Phone_Num = in.next().trim();

          if(Phone_Num.length()!=10)
            System.out.println("Please enter correct phone number!");
          else
            break;
        }

        listOfRecords.add(new Record(First_name, Last_name, Phone_Num));
          choice = listOfRecords.size();
      }

      //Change phone number
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("p"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("Enter new phone number: ");
            Num = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).changePhone(Num);
        }
      }

      //Exit
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
      {
        System.out.println("Quit");
        System.exit(1);
      }


      else

      if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
      {

        String testName;
        int test=0;
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
          First_name = in.next().trim();

        for(int i=0; i<listOfRecords.size(); i++)
        {
          testName = listOfRecords.get(i).getFirst();
          if(testName.equals(First_name))
          {
            choice=i+1;
            test++;
          }
        }

        //print if no match found
        if(test==1);
          System.out.println("No Record found");
      }

      else
        System.out.println("Choice not correct");
    }
  }

  //print menu
  static void Menu()
  {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\t(a) Show all records");
    System.out.println("\t(d) Delete the current record");
    System.out.println("\t(f) Change the first name in the current record");
    System.out.println("\t(l) Change the last name in the current record");
    System.out.println("\t(n) Add a new record");
    System.out.println("\t(p) Change the phone number in the current record");
    System.out.println("\t(q) Quit");
    System.out.println("\t(s) Select a record from the record list to become current record");
  }
}
      }

      //change first name of choice Record
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("New first name: ");
            First = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).changeFirst(First);
        }
      }

      //Change last name of selected record
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("New last name: ");
            Last = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).changeLast(Last);
        }
      }

      //add new contact

      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
      {
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
                First_name = in.next().trim();
        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
                Last_name = in.next().trim();
        //check in valid phone number input
        //if phone number does not equal 10 then reprompt
        while(true)
        {
          System.out.print("Enter phone number");
                  Phone_Num = in.next().trim();

          if(Phone_Num.length()!=10)
            System.out.println("Please enter correct phone number!");
          else
            break;
        }

        listOfRecords.add(new Record(First_name, Last_name, Phone_Num));
          choice = listOfRecords.size();
      }

      //Change phone number
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("p"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("Enter new phone number: ");
            Num = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).changePhone(Num);
        }
      }

      //Exit
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
      {
        System.out.println("Quit");
        System.exit(1);
      }


      else

      if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
      {

        String testName;
        int test=0;
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
          First_name = in.next().trim();

        for(int i=0; i<listOfRecords.size(); i++)
        {
          testName = listOfRecords.get(i).getFirst();
          if(testName.equals(First_name))
          {
            choice=i+1;
            test++;
          }
        }

        //print if no match found
        if(test==1);
          System.out.println("No Record found");
      }

      else
        System.out.println("Choice not correct");
    }
  }

  //print menu
  static void Menu()
  {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("\t(a) Show all records");
    System.out.println("\t(d) Delete the current record");
    System.out.println("\t(f) Change the first name in the current record");
    System.out.println("\t(l) Change the last name in the current record");
    System.out.println("\t(n) Add a new record");
    System.out.println("\t(p) Change the phone number in the current record");
    System.out.println("\t(q) Quit");
    System.out.println("\t(s) Select a record from the record list to become current record");
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "not running properly" be specific. What exactly is the error causing? Or what is the behavior of the code compared to the expected behavior of the code. Nobody is going to look through your code without knowing what they're looking for.

Comment: Cut your program back to a much smaller version, get that to work and then add functionality.  You've bitten off too much in a first effort.

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected your code. I was able to successfully execute and insert few records as well.

Below are 2 classes `Phonedir.java`  and `Record.java`.

`Phonedir.java`

```
package stackoverflow;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Phonedir
{

    //print menu
      static void Menu()
      {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("\t(a) Show all records");
        System.out.println("\t(d) Delete the current record");
        System.out.println("\t(f) Change the first name in the current record");
        System.out.println("\t(l) Change the last name in the current record");
        System.out.println("\t(n) Add a new record");
        System.out.println("\t(p) Change the phone number in the current record");
        System.out.println("\t(q) Quit");
        System.out.println("\t(s) Select a record from the record list to become current record");
      }

  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    String First_name, Last_name, Phone_Num;
    String First, Last, Num;
    int choice=0;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    LinkedList<Record> listOfRecords = new LinkedList<Record>();

    System.out.println("A Program to keep a Phone Directory:");

    //looping menu
    while(true)
    {
        Menu();

      //enter the choice
      if(choice==0)
        System.out.println("No choice selected");
      else  
        System.out.println(listOfRecords.get(choice-1));

      System.out.print("Enter the choice ");
        String command = in.next().trim();

      //show all entries
      if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
      {
        System.out.println();



        //for loop
        for(int i=0; i<listOfRecords.size(); i++) {
            Record record = listOfRecords.get(i);
             System.out.println(record.getFirstName() +" "+  record.getLastName() +" "+ record.getPhone());
        }


      }

      //Delete choice
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Deleted: "+listOfRecords.remove(choice-1));
          choice=0;          //update choice counter of reference of linked list
        }

      }

      //change first name of choice Record
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("New first name: ");
            First = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).setFirstName(First);
        }
      }

      //Change last name of selected record
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("New last name: ");
            Last = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).setLastName(Last);
        }
      }

      //add new contact

      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
      {
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
                First_name = in.next().trim();
        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
                Last_name = in.next().trim();
        //check in valid phone number input
        //if phone number does not equal 10 then reprompt
        while(true)
        {
          System.out.print("Enter phone number");
                  Phone_Num = in.next().trim();

          if(Phone_Num.length()!=10)
            System.out.println("Please enter correct phone number!");
          else
            break;
        }

        listOfRecords.add(new Record(First_name, Last_name, Phone_Num));
          choice = listOfRecords.size();
      }

      //Change phone number
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("p"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("Enter new phone number: ");
            Num = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).setPhone(Num);
        }
      }

      //Exit
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
      {
        System.out.println("Quit");
        System.exit(1);
      }


      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
      {

        String testName;
        int test=0;
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
          First_name = in.next().trim();

        for(int i=0; i<listOfRecords.size(); i++)
        {
          testName = listOfRecords.get(i).getFirstName();
          if(testName.equals(First_name))
          {
            choice=i+1;
            test++;
          }
        }


      }



      //change first name of choice Record
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("New first name: ");
            First = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).setFirstName(First);
        }
      }

      //Change last name of selected record
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("l"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("New last name: ");
            Last = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).setLastName(Last);
        }
      }

      //add new contact

      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("n"))
      {
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
                First_name = in.next().trim();
        System.out.print("Enter last name: ");
                Last_name = in.next().trim();
        //check in valid phone number input
        //if phone number does not equal 10 then reprompt
        while(true)
        {
          System.out.print("Enter phone number");
                  Phone_Num = in.next().trim();

          if(Phone_Num.length()!=10)
            System.out.println("Please enter correct phone number!");
          else
            break;
        }

        listOfRecords.add(new Record(First_name, Last_name, Phone_Num));
          choice = listOfRecords.size();
      }

      //Change phone number
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("p"))
      {
        if(choice==0)
          System.out.println("No Record selected");
        else
        {
          System.out.print("Enter new phone number: ");
            Num = in.next().trim();

          listOfRecords.get(choice-1).setPhone(Num);
        }
      }

      //Exit
      else if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("q"))
      {
        System.out.println("Quit");
        System.exit(1);
      }


      else

      if(command.equalsIgnoreCase("s"))
      {

        String testName;
        int test=0;
        System.out.print("Enter first name: ");
          First_name = in.next().trim();

        for(int i=0; i<listOfRecords.size(); i++)
        {
          testName = listOfRecords.get(i).getFirstName();
          if(testName.equals(First_name))
          {
            choice=i+1;
            test++;
          }
        }

        //print if no match found
        if(test==1);
          System.out.println("No Record found");
      }

      else
        System.out.println("Choice not correct");
    }
  }


}
```

`Record.java`

```
package stackoverflow;

public class Record {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String phone;

    public Record(String firstName, String lastName, String phone){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment yet, so I'll make this an answer.

1. Your code example is not very readable. Maybe you could try to make it shorter.
2. You have a lot of code outside the class. Check your parenteses!
3. Type T is not defined in `LinkedList<T> listOfTs = new LinkedList<T>();`
4. I see multiples `static void Menu()` methods in your code. Use a unique  name for each method.
5. Split up your code into smaller parts.